# Examples of proofs that use the (Hardy-Littlewood) Circle Method

Tags: number-theory, examples-counterexamples, analytic-number-theory

I will be doing my bachelor thesis on the Hardy-Littlewood circle method, where in part I want to assess the value of this method. To do this, I want to look at some proofs that make use of this method. So,

- Can you give any examples of proofs that use the circle method?

I want to see how the method contributed to the proof, including how the theorem was proved beforehand (if at all).

I will be using the following resource a lot,

https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/BrownClasses/1/circlemethod.pdf

It contains a lot of very useful things, but I was hoping to find some other, perhaps more obscure, proofs to investigate.

Comment: Can you give examples for circle method proofs you found by googling? What about weak Goldbach?

Comment: Updated to reflect a missing nuance

Comment: Well, Weak Goldbach is really more interesting than some "more obscure" topic. Also have a look [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-brief-summary-of-the-circle-method-used-to-prove-the-weak-Goldbach-conjecture) for example, how to use circle method for it, or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164020/the-significance-and-acceptance-of-helfgott-s-proof-of-the-weak-goldbach-conject). This should make a nice bachelor thesis.