# Does the partition function $p(n)$ generate infinite number of primes

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, integer-partitions

Wikipedia says

> As of June 2022, the largest known prime number among the values of $p(n)$ is $p(1289844341)$, with $40,000$ decimal digits

citing [1].

Is it known whether the partition function generates infinite primes? Please provide references to support or disprove the claim.

**Context:** I am working on a proof and it involves partition functions on one side of the equation. It would be easier to proceed if the partition function generates an infinitude of primes.

**References:**

[1]: PrimePage Primes: p(1289844341), primes.utm.edu, URL retrieved 30 June 2022: https://primes.utm.edu/primes/page.php?id=130336

Comment: The [OEIS sequence A002496]/(https://oeis.org) "Primes of the form k^2+1" first comment is "It is conjectured that this sequence is infinite, but this has never been proved.". What makes you think that it would be easier for the partition function? In fact [OEIS sequence A049575](https://oeis.org/A049575) is "Prime partition numbers" and the numbers grow very quickly though no comments about if there are infinitely many.

Comment: It is surprising that this number is the largest known prime number of this kind , unless it is in fact the last upto a very high limit. I would expect the latter possibility. $p(n)$ is so natural that surely someone tested significantly higher numbers. A Smarandache prime $Sm(n)$ would be also of great interest (although it is base-dependent) but none is known. It is a number like $1234567891011121314151617$ , we concatenate the positive integers from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: $p(n)-p(n-1)$ also produces many primes. Has this been checked for primality as well ? OEIS contains all kind of sequences , so maybe someone had this idea.

Comment: The first $30$ entries would be $$[4, 5, 8, 15, 20, 25, 30, 103, 114, 191, 214, 253, 271, 314, 398, 494, 514, 598, 634, 746, 952, 963, 1040, 1066, 1137, 1293, 1320, 1378, 1450, 1496]$$ in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very likely true that there are infinitely many prime values of $p(n)$, but [as usual](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4523193/are-there-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-x-we-probably-dont-know), this is very unlikely to be provable with our current understanding.  The usual heuristic for the number of prime values of a sequence $a_n$ with $n < x$ is $$\sum_{n<x} \frac{1}{\log(a_n)},$$ which in this case diverges because the asymptotic formula $$\log(p(n)) \sim \pi \sqrt{2n/3}$$ (reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)#Approximation_formulas)) implies $$\sum_{n<x} \frac{1}{\log(p(n))} \sim \frac{\sqrt{6x}}{\pi},$$ which diverges as $n \to \infty$.  This heuristic needs some mild corrections due to known [congruence properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_congruences) of $p(n)$ due to Ramanaujan, Atkin, Ono, etc.  However, numerical evidence supports the claim that it is at least on the right order of magnitude:  according to the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A046063), there are $4967$ values of $n < 10^8$ such that $p(n)$ is prime, whereas the naive heuristic would predict $$\sum_{n<10^8} \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{2n/3}} \approx 7796,$$ and correcting for the three congruences known to Ramanaujan gives $$\sum_{n<10^8} \frac 45 \cdot \frac 67 \cdot \frac{10}{11} \cdot \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{2n/3}} \approx 4860.$$

As a side note:  Peter mentions in a comment that it is surprising that the largest known prime value of $p(n)$ has only $40000$ digits, and that perhaps this indicates there are no larger ones up to a reasonable limit.  The actual explanation for this is less exciting:  since we cannot ordinarily factor $p(n) \pm 1$, we have no faster method than [elliptic curve primality proving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_primality) to *prove* the primality of $p(n)$, even when it appears to be prime.  (ECPP is currently only practical up to several tens of thousands of digits; that $40000$-digit prime previously held the record.  See discussion [here](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showpost.php?p=536464&postcount=21) and [here](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=20205).)  Indeed, there are several larger values of $p(n)$ (see [here](http://www.primenumbers.net/prptop/searchform.php?form=numbpart%28%3F%29&action=Search)) that are known to be probable primes.

Comment: (+1) for clarifying that there are more cases just not proven prime.